# What is wrong with this XSD from my XSD Generator?

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I am creating a XSD Generator for my Java code to run on the fly when called. It is only generating XSD's when needed. It is using a sax parser and generating the following XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.google.com/types/evt/SendCCToAlternateAddr/v1" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:NS1="SendCCToAlternateAddrEvtType">
<xsd:element name="SendCCToAlternateAddrEvtType">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="CommonAttributes" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="999">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="EventName" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="999" type="xsd:normalizedString"/>
<xsd:element name="EventVer" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="999" type="xsd:normalizedString"/>
<xsd:element name="BusTransEffDt" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="999" type="xsd:normalizedString"/>
<xsd:element name="BusTransRecTS" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="999" type="xsd:normalizedString"/>
<xsd:element name="PubSystemNm" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="999" type="xsd:normalizedString"/>
<xsd:element name="EventType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="999" type="xsd:normalizedString"/>
<xsd:element name="EventSubType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="999" type="xsd:normalizedString"/>
<xsd:element name="OrgUnitNm" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="999" type="xsd:normalizedString"/>
<xsd:element name="Channel" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="999" type="xsd:normalizedString"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="PmtCardBasic" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="999">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="PartyPDId" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="999" type="xsd:normalizedString"/>
<xsd:element name="PartyIdTypeCd" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="999" type="xsd:normalizedString"/>
<xsd:element name="ArrangementId" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="999" type="xsd:normalizedString"/>
<xsd:element name="MajBusUnitCd" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="999" type="xsd:normalizedString"/>
<xsd:element name="PrdSvcLinBusCd" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="999" type="xsd:normalizedString"/>
<xsd:element name="PaymentCardDetail" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="999">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="MaskedCardNr" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="999" type="xsd:normalizedString"/>
<xsd:element name="CardTypeDc" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="999" type="xsd:normalizedString"/>
<xsd:element name="AlternateAddressInd" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="999" type="xsd:normalizedString"/>
<xsd:element name="CreatedByPartyPDId" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="999" type="xsd:normalizedString"/>
<xsd:element name="CreatedByPartyIdTypeCd" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="999" type="xsd:normalizedString"/>
<xsd:element name="PaymentCardEncryptedNr" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="999" type="xsd:normalizedString"/>
<xsd:element name="PaymentCardDetail" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="999">
<xsd:complexType>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="MaskedCardNr" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="999" type="xsd:normalizedString"/>
<xsd:element name="CardTypeDc" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="999" type="xsd:normalizedString"/>
<xsd:element name="AlternateAddressInd" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="999" type="xsd:normalizedString"/>
<xsd:element name="CreatedByPartyPDId" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="999" type="xsd:normalizedString"/>
<xsd:element name="CreatedByPartyIdTypeCd" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="999" type="xsd:normalizedString"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="ServiceTypeDc" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="999" type="xsd:normalizedString"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

The XML is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NS1:SendCCToAlternateAddrEvtType xmlns:NS1="http://www.google.com/types/evt/SendCCToAlternateAddr/v1">
<CommonAttributes>
    <EventName>sendCCToAlternateAddr</EventName>
    <EventVer>1.0</EventVer>
    <BusTransEffDt>2015-10-24</BusTransEffDt>
    <BusTransRecTS>2015-10-24T13:12:02.276-06:00</BusTransRecTS>
    <PubSystemNm>UpdateServices</PubSystemNm>
    <EventType>*</EventType>
    <EventSubType>*</EventSubType>
    <OrgUnitNm>yioyiu7y</OrgUnitNm>
    <Channel>employee</Channel>
</CommonAttributes>
<PmtCardBasic>
    <PartyPDId>34221717</PartyPDId>
    <PartyIdTypeCd>*</PartyIdTypeCd>
    <ArrangementId>XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-</ArrangementId>
    <MajBusUnitCd>BNK</MajBusUnitCd>
    <PrdSvcLinBusCd>DMD</PrdSvcLinBusCd>
    <PaymentCardDetail>
        <MaskedCardNr>XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-</MaskedCardNr>
        <CardTypeDc>MasterCard</CardTypeDc>
        <AlternateAddressInd>Y</AlternateAddressInd>
        <CreatedByPartyPDId>2341223</CreatedByPartyPDId>
        <CreatedByPartyIdTypeCd>EMPE</CreatedByPartyIdTypeCd>
        <PaymentCardEncryptedNr>999493076694449</PaymentCardEncryptedNr>
            <PaymentCardDetail>
                <MaskedCardNr>XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-</MaskedCardNr>
                <CardTypeDc>MasterCard</CardTypeDc>
                <AlternateAddressInd>Y</AlternateAddressInd>
                <CreatedByPartyPDId>2341223</CreatedByPartyPDId>
                <CreatedByPartyIdTypeCd>EMPE</CreatedByPartyIdTypeCd>
            </PaymentCardDetail>
    </PaymentCardDetail>
</PmtCardBasic>
<ServiceTypeDc>sendCCToAlternateAddr</ServiceTypeDc>
</NS1:SendCCToAlternateAddrEvtType>
```

I have looked at online generators to validate my XSD but my XSD seems to go farther in validation with JAVA than the other generated XSD's from third parties.

Error I am getting:

```
ERROR : cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'CommonAttributes'. One of '{"http://www.google.com/types/evt/SendCCToAlternateAddr/v1":CommonAttributes, "http://www.google.com/types/evt/SendCCToAlternateAddr/v1":PmtCardBasic, "http://www.google.com/types/evt/SendCCToAlternateAddr/v1":ServiceTypeDc}' is expected.
```

Any help on how to get this XSD to valid would be a great help.

Comment: You don't seem to be using the namespace that it is looking for. It is specifically looking for `"http://www.usaa.com/types/evt/SendCCToAlternateAddr/v1":CommonAttributes`. Declare a namespace for `"http://www.usaa.com/types/evt/SendCCToAlternateAddr/v1"` aliased to `sccalt` or something and decorate your elements with with the `sccalt` like this `<sccalt:CommonAttribute>...</sccalt:CommonAttribute>`, etc...

Comment: So in the header element make the `xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.usaa.com/types/evt/SendCCToAlternateAddr/v1"` ..... actually:  `xsd:schema targetNamespace="sccalt`. Sorry I am confused. I am completely new to XML's and XSD's.  @gmiley

Answer (score 0):

You are not using your namespaces right. I would advise you to check out the following example and to implement yours the similar way... I tried to validate mine everywhere, and it worked like charm.

XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema 
attributeFormDefault="qualified" 
elementFormDefault="qualified" 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema http://myNamespaceUrl/taxonomie/1"
targetNamespace="http://myNamespaceUrl/taxonomie/1"
xmlns="http://myNamespaceUrl/taxonomie/1">  
    <xs:element name="taxonomie">
    ...
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<taxonomie xmlns="http://bva.sozvers.at/lava/taxonomie/1">
    <taxon>
    ...
    </taxon>
</taxonomie>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define your namespace and decorate your XML elements properly, judging by what you have up there, You have a namespace defined, but it is not the one the XSD is looking for. The following should work for you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NS1:SendCCToAlternateAddrEvtType xmlns:NS1="http://www.usaa.com/types/evt/SendCCToAlternateAddr/v1">
    <NS1:CommonAttributes>
        <NS1:EventName>sendCCToAlternateAddr</NS1:EventName>
        <NS1:EventVer>1.0</NS1:EventVer>
        <NS1:BusTransEffDt>2015-10-24</NS1:BusTransEffDt>
        <NS1:BusTransRecTS>2015-10-24T13:12:02.276-06:00</NS1:BusTransRecTS>
        <NS1:PubSystemNm>UpdateServices</NS1:PubSystemNm>
        <NS1:EventType>*</NS1:EventType>
        <NS1:EventSubType>*</NS1:EventSubType>
        <NS1:OrgUnitNm>yioyiu7y</NS1:OrgUnitNm>
        <NS1:Channel>employee</NS1:Channel>
    </NS1:CommonAttributes>
    <NS1:PmtCardBasic>
        <NS1:PartyPDId>34221717</NS1:PartyPDId>
        <NS1:PartyIdTypeCd>*</NS1:PartyIdTypeCd>
        <NS1:ArrangementId>XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-</NS1:ArrangementId>
        <NS1:MajBusUnitCd>BNK</NS1:MajBusUnitCd>
        <NS1:PrdSvcLinBusCd>DMD</NS1:PrdSvcLinBusCd>
        <NS1:PaymentCardDetail>
            <NS1:MaskedCardNr>XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-</NS1:MaskedCardNr>
            <NS1:CardTypeDc>MasterCard</NS1:CardTypeDc>
            <NS1:AlternateAddressInd>Y</NS1:AlternateAddressInd>
            <NS1:CreatedByPartyPDId>2341223</NS1:CreatedByPartyPDId>
            <NS1:CreatedByPartyIdTypeCd>EMPE</NS1:CreatedByPartyIdTypeCd>
            <NS1:PaymentCardEncryptedNr>999493076694449</NS1:PaymentCardEncryptedNr>
            <NS1:PaymentCardDetail>
                <NS1:MaskedCardNr>XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-</NS1:MaskedCardNr>
                <NS1:CardTypeDc>MasterCard</NS1:CardTypeDc>
                <NS1:AlternateAddressInd>Y</NS1:AlternateAddressInd>
                <NS1:CreatedByPartyPDId>2341223</NS1:CreatedByPartyPDId>
                <NS1:CreatedByPartyIdTypeCd>EMPE</NS1:CreatedByPartyIdTypeCd>
            </NS1:PaymentCardDetail>
        </NS1:PaymentCardDetail>
    </NS1:PmtCardBasic>
    <NS1:ServiceTypeDc>sendCCToAlternateAddr</NS1:ServiceTypeDc>
</NS1:SendCCToAlternateAddrEvtType>
```

Notice the change: `http://www.google.com/types/evt/SendCCToAlternateAddr/v1` to `http://www.usaa.com/types/evt/SendCCToAlternateAddr/v1`. I also decorated every element. You can get around having to do that, but I find it better practice to explicitly state what namespace each element is using as several could be used in a single XML, and most XML is generated by code anyway so it doesn't take any extra time really.

One thing I also noticed, the XSD you provided above has the `http://www.google.com/types/evt/SendCCToAlternateAddr/v1` namespace in it, however, the error you are reporting is stating that it is looking for `http://www.usaa.com/types/evt/SendCCToAlternateAddr/v1`, somewhere you have a mismatch as to what the expected namespace is. You should look into that first before you go around changing your namespaces in your code.